# How to add JPanel to JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

I have added one `JPanel` to the `JScrollPane`. But the main panel is not scrolling. My problem is like this:

```
JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
MainPanel.setBounds(width/2,height/10,width/5,height/5);
MainPanel.setLayout(null);

JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(MainPanel);
scrollPane.setBounds(width/2,height/10,width/5,height/5);
//Added scrollPane to MainFrame Panel
MainFrame.add(scrollPane);

//Added four JPanel to MainPanel
JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
subPanel.setbounds(10,20,50,50);
MainPanel.add(subPanel);

JPanel subPanel2 = new JPanel();
subPanel2.setbounds(50,60,50,50);
MainPanel.add(subPanel2);

JPanel subPanel3 = new JPanel();
subPanel3.setbounds(50,100,50,50);
MainPanel.add(subPanel3);

JPanel subPanel4 = new JPanel();
subPanel4.setbounds(50,60,50,50);
MainPanel.add(subPanel4);
```

I didn't see the `subPanel3` and `subPanel4`. Now I'm able to see the vertical scroll bar but it is not working.

Comment: Using `setBounds()` aloing with `setLayout(null)` you're basically setting the size of your main panel which happens to be the size of the scrollpane - so there is nothing to scroll.

Comment: @Thomas I remove the setBound() but still, I'm not able to see the subPanel3 and 4 .

Comment: *"I remove the setBound()"* Remove the `null` layout then [edit] to show a [mcve] of the change code.

Comment: As an aside, add at least one label to each panel, otherwise the preferred size will be 0 x 0.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas  it works when I removed the setBound() and setLayout(null) from MainPanel.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson for your help.

Comment: @Thomas Can you upgrade your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use layouts instead of setBounds(). GridBagLayout, GridLayout, FlowLayout, BoxLayout and BorderLayout will be useful. Documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

And append this at the bottom of the code:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setView(MainPanel);
```

Comment: `scrollPane.getViewport().setView(MainPanel);` is not necessary, given `JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(MainPanel);` (the panel is passed in the constructor and will be added to the viewport).